# Visual Studio 2022 on Mac missing all simulation devices

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, xamarin, ios-simulator, visual-studio-mac

I have Visual Studio 17.5.4 (build 8) installed on my Mac with OS Ventura 13.0.1  and Xcode version 14.3

The iOS simulation devices have all disappeared.
I made a dummy project in Xcode and I am able to run it in a simulator from Xcode, but not from VS.

All I can see is this...

[image: iOS simulators missing from VS 2022 mac]

What I tried so far and didn't help

1. Tried using an older Xcode version, but I can't install an older Xcode version on this OS
2. Restarted the system
3. Tried relinking Xcode.app
   [image: List item]
4. Restarted VS

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Visual Studio for Mac](https://apprankportal.com/apps/visual-studio-for-mac) latest version. This is version 17.5.0.124
https://apprankportal.com/apps/visual-studio-for-mac

Answer (score 0):

After wasting a good 6 hours on this, I stumbled upon this thread. After trying different xcode versions, the latest v14.3 with the xamarin-ios16.4.0.6.pkg fixed the problem.
Follow the details in this thread: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/17561